# How can I execute multiple cmd commands using Python code

Tags: python, cmd

Hello I am having this problem where i want to automatically check the system32 file folder with the sfc cmd commands like sfc /verifyonly but the problem is that I can execute only one line in the cmd but I need to execute two and don't know how to execute a second one

```
import os

os.system("start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k sfc")
```

I need another command for sfc /verifyonly so the program would work fully automatic can somebody help with anything pls

I tried a lot of things but nothing seemed to work for me or i am just really stupid and can't find the exact command i should be using

Comment: [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) is deprecated since many years and should not be used anymore in newly written Python scripts using Python 3.x. There should be used the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) which is a Python wrapper module for the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) which is also used by `cmd.exe` to run other executables.

Comment: The usage of the `subprocess` module gives a Python script writer full control on how an executable is run with `CreateProcess` without or with usage of an appropriate filled out [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure to control if a console window is shown or not for a console application, where it is shown on screen and in which size, etc. The Python script can just run in a loop multiple times one of the three `subprocess` functions to run one executable after the other without using `cmd.exe` at all.

Comment: By the way: `sfc` is with its fully qualified file name `%SystemRoot%\System32\sfc.exe`. The string value of the environment variable `SystemRoot` can be get from within a Python script using [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ). The posted Python script code line is complete nonsense taking into account that `os.system` results in execution of `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /c` with the command line as defined in Python script appended as additional arguments.. How many `cmd.exe` do you start just to run `%SystemRoot%\System32\sfc.exe` with `CreateProcess`?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the docs for [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) they mention the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module as being a more recent development within python that supports multiple systems level processes